# Delete or not after copy/load

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

That's probably a trick question, but I'm not sure;

Do I have to call delete after :

- `QImage::copy()`
- `QImage::load(QString)`
- `QPixmap::fromImage(QImage)`

By delete I mean, deleting it when I don't need it any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QImage objects are not special in how they are created and destroyed. On the stack or with new/delete or whatever, the rules are the same as for all C++ objects.

QImage is [implicitly shared](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html#implicit-data-sharing), so copying it is cheap (like a shared pointer) but it performs copy-on-write to preserve value semantics.

Short story, you probably don't ever have to new/delete a QImage, just pass it around as a value and quit worrying.

You don't *have* to do any special deleting after calling copy/load methods, although you might want to assign `my_image=QImage()` to release cached data or something.